# How do I conditionally select variables in PROC SQL?

Tags: sas

I have calculated a frequency table in a previous step. Excerpt below:

[image]

I want to automatically drop all variables from this table where the frequency is missing. In the excerpt above, that would mean the variables "Exkl_UtgUtl_Taxi_kvot" and "Exkl_UtgUtl_Driv_kvot" would need to be dropped.

I try the following step in PROC SQL (which ideally I will repeat for all variables in the table):

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE test3 as
SELECT (CASE WHEN Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg_kvot!=. THEN Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg_kvot ELSE NULL END)
FROM  stickprovsstorlekar;
quit;
```

This fails, however, since SAS does not like NULL values. How do I do this?

I tried just writing:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE test3 as
SELECT (CASE WHEN Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg_kvot!=. THEN Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg_kvot)
FROM  stickprovsstorlekar;
quit;
```

But that just generates a variable with an automatically generated name (like DATA_007). I want all variables containing missing values to be totally excluded from the results.

Comment: Please show example input and output data.  "frequency table" is not enough of a description to understand what your data looks like and how to determine which variables to exclude.

Comment: Like so?

Checking out for the day, but thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Better, but it is very hard to code from photographs of data.

Comment: How exactly would I go about creating a repex in SAS?

I've mostly coded in R before

Comment: Just post the data step that creates the data from in-line data. `data have; input var1 var2 ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 10 variables, where `var1`, `var3`, `var5`, `var7`, and `var9` have missing values in the first observation. We want to select only the variables with no missing observations.

```
var1    var2    var3    var4    var5    var6    var7    var8    var9    var10
.      8       .       9       .       6       .       1       .       4
5      1       2       7       2       7       2       9       7       7
5      9       7       7       6       8       5       6       4       9
...
```

First, let's find all variables that have missing observations:

```
proc means data=have noprint;
    var _NUMERIC_;
    output out=missing nmiss=;
run;
```

Then transpose this output table so it's easier to work with:

```
proc transpose data=missing out=missing_tpose;
run;
```

We now have a table that looks like this:

```
_NAME_  COL1
_TYPE_  0
_FREQ_  10
var1    1
var2    0
var3    1
var4    0
var5    1
var6    0
var7    1
var8    0
var9    1
var10   0
```

When COL1 is > 0 and the name is not `_TYPE_` or `_FREQ_`, that means the variable has missing values. Let's extract the name of the variable from `_NAME_` into a comma-separated list.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select _NAME_
    into :vars separated by ','
    from missing_tpose
    where COL1 = 0 AND _NAME_ NOT IN('_TYPE_', '_FREQ_')
    ;
quit;
```

`%put &vars` and you'll see all of the non-missing values that can be passed into SQL.

```
var2,var4,var6,var8,var10
```

Now we have a dynamic way to select variables with only non-missing values.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select &vars
        from have
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: ?? Why use ODS?? Why not just use the OUTPUT statement in PROC MEANS? `output out=summary nmiss= ;`

Comment: I dunno, something I learned from a tip I got back in the day. I updated it to use the output table instead.